# If $f$ is an affine map and $f(0) = 0$, then $f$ is a linear map.

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-analysis, affine-geometry

> If $f$ is affine and $f(0) = 0$, then $f$ is a linear map.
>   Define $f(x) = T(x) - T(0)$, where $T$ is an affine map from $R^n$ to $R^k$.

I see that I would have to show that $f(ax) = af(x)$, which means $T(ax) - T(0) = a[T(x)-T(0)]$, but how would I show this equality?

I see that $f(x + y) = f(x) + f(y)$ iff $T(0) = 0$, but I don't see how I would show $f(ax) = af(x)$ since $aT(x) \neq T(ax).$

The definition of an affine map:

> Let $\{p_0, .., p_n\} \subseteq R^n$ be affine independent and let $A$ denote the affine set is spans.  An affine map $T: A \rightarrow R^k$ (for some $k \gt 1)$ is a function satisfying $T(\sum t_ip_i) = \sum t_i T(p_i)$ whenever $\sum t_i = 1$.  The restriction to $[p_0, ..., p_n]$, which is the convex set spanned by $\{p_0, ..., p_n\}$, is also an affine map.

Comment: Is $\mathbb{R}^n$ an affine space, and if so, what is an explicit formula for the general affine map?

Comment: I'm not sure of any general affine map formula.  The definition provided in the question is the only definition so far used in the book I'm reading.

Comment: Choose $\{p_i\}$ to be the normal basis in $R^n$>

Comment: @Olba12 What do you mean by normal basis?

Comment: If the points $p_i$ are affine independent, then $A = \mathbb R^n$. Or do you consider $n+1$ points in $\mathbb R^m$ with $ m \ge n$?

Answer (score 1):

Let $f:X \rightarrow Y$ be an affine map between vector spaces over $\mathbb{R}$ with $f(0)=0$

**Step 1:** $f(\lambda x)=\lambda f(x)$

If $\lambda\in [0,1]$, we have $f(\lambda x)=f(\lambda x+(1-\lambda)0)=\lambda f(x)$.

Furthermore $0=f(-x/2+x/2)=f(-x)/2+f(x)/2$, which means $f(-x)=-f(x)$.

This implies that $f(-\lambda x)=-f(\lambda x )=-\lambda f(x)$ for $\lambda\in[0,1]$.

Combining these facts, for $\lambda\in [-1,1]$, we have established that $f(\lambda x)=\lambda f(x)$.

Fix $\lambda \in[-1,1]\setminus\{0\}$ and write  $f(x)=f(\lambda \frac{1}{\lambda}x)=\lambda f(\frac{1}{\lambda} x)$. Thus:

$$f\left(\frac{1}{\lambda}x\right)=\frac{1}{\lambda}f(x) \quad \text{for $\lambda\in [-1,1]\setminus\{0\}$}$$

But $1/\lambda$ spans $(-\infty, \infty)\setminus\{0\}$, so this proves linearity.

**Step 2:** $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$

Using the fact $f$ is affine and multiplication linear yields:

$$f(x+y)=f\left(\frac{2x+2y}{2}\right)=\frac{1}{2}f(2x)+\frac{1}{2}f(2y)=f(x)+f(y)$$

---

This has nothing to do with the original question, but is a nice consequence of what we have proved:

**Bonus result:** If $f: X\rightarrow Y$ is a surjective isometry between real normed vector space (that is, $\lVert f(x)-f(y) \rVert=\lVert x-y \rVert$) and $f(0)=0$, then $f$ is linear.

This follows from [Mazur Ulam's Theorem](https://lmb.univ-fcomte.fr/IMG/pdf/coursLens2010.pdf), which implies a surjective isometry is affine. Then we argue as in the OP's question to conclude $f$ is linear.

Answer (score 0):

Your thoughts are conspicuously missing the key step of writing down what it means for $T$ to be an affine map.

Comment: Edited to include the definition of an affine map.

Answer (score 0):

let $(p_n)_n$ be the standard basis in $\mathbb{R^n}$, ie $\sum p_n = 1$, and $p_n$ spans $\mathbb{R^n}$. Thus $T$ must be in the form of $T(x) = kx + m.$ Can you finish from here?

Answer (score 0):

What do you do, is only reading the first part of the chapter four of the book foundation of optimization by Osman Güler. 
Definition 4.1 A nonempty subset A of a vector space E is called an aﬃne set if for points x and y in A, the line passing through x and y is contained
in A; in other words,
x, y ∈ A ⇒ ℓ := {x + t(y − x) = (1 − t)x + ty : t ∈ R} ⊆ A.
Let A and B be aﬃne sets in vector spaces E and F , respectively. A map
F : A → B is called an aﬃne map if
F ((1 − t)x + ty) = (1 − t)F (x) + tF(y) for all t ∈ R.
Theorem 4.4. If A ⊆ E is an aﬃne subset of E, and a ∈ A is an arbitrary
point, then L := A − a = {y − a : y ∈ A} is a linear subspace of E, which is independent of a ∈ A;consequently,
A = a + L, and L = A − A = {y − z : y, z ∈ A}. 
Let F : A → B be a map between two aﬃne sets A and B. It is easy to
verify that F is an aﬃne map if and only if its graph
gr(F ) := {(x, F (x)) : x ∈ A} ⊆ A × B is an aﬃne set.
Since the gr(F) is an aﬃne set in A × B
Using Theorem 4.4. (0,0) = (a -a,F(a)- F(a) ) = ((a,F(a)) - (a,F(a)) is consequently a linear subspace of L := A × B - A × B providing F(x) is a linear map.

Comment: Maybe I had to recall the following Theorem again from The above book.Theorem 4.7. Let F : A → B be an aﬃne map between aﬃne sets A ⊆ E1
and B ⊆ E2.Let L = A − A and M = B − B be the linear vector spaces associated with A
and B, respectively. The function F¯ : L → M deﬁned by
F¯(x − a) := F (x) − F (a)
is a linear map that is independent of a ∈ A. This shows  the map is linearly independent.